# What is causing this SnipMate message?

Tags: vim, vi, snipmate

I have just started using the Vim plugin SnipMate.  When I create an HTML file (with filetype .html), go into insert mode, and type "html" and a tab, I see this message at the bottom of my screen:

```
1*  1. Users/me/.vim/bundle/vim-snippets javascript-jquery default
2:  2. Users/me/.vim/bundle/vim-snippets html default

__InputList__
select snippet by name (filter: ; press <F1> for help) [glob]
```

I'm not sure why this is happening.  How can I configure SnipMate so that it knows that when I type "html" I always want the second option?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: I think it's thrown by tlib_vim for SnipMate https://github.com/tomtom/tlib_vim/blob/9734d8d9e4f7b7b91272123463a62759aef31556/autoload/tlib/input.vim#L119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message was caused by an "html" snippet in the file vim-snippets/snippets/javascript/javascript-jquery.snippets.  Once I commented that snippet out, the message stopped occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.
I had a similar error on the bottom of my vim screen:

1 1* 1. html bundle/vim-snippets html.snippets

2 2: 2. javascript bundle/vim-snippets javascript-jquery.snippets

There is already a snippet called html in the 
~/.vim/bundle/vim-snippets/snippets/javascript-jquery.snippets file.
You should comment out these two lines with the # sign, like this:

'# snippet html 
̈́'#        ${1:obj}.html('${2:Some text **and bold!**}')

Someone should fix this problem.
Installing Vim plugins should be easy, not complicated! :-(